# Type requires 8 bytes of alignment and the default allocator only guarantees 4 bytes

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

I'm getting this warning (with `-Weverything`) when trying to compile the following:

```
main_controller * mc = new main_controller(realm);
```

The `main_controller` type is the one that appears to require 8 bytes. I couldn't find much info about this warning out there. I understand that there's a possible alignment mismatch, but how can this be solved?

Edit: for clarification purposes. The `main_controller` class contains several statically allocated objects (it's a deep graph). Still, it doesn't seem relevant exactly how the object is constructed, only that it's not aligned to four bytes. There's really not much more to it. I'll try creating a simpler object that replicates the problem, though (haven't managed to do that so far).

Edit: the warning *is* the title. Literally, the compiler gives:

> > Type 'main_controller' requires 8 bytes of alignment and the default allocator only guarantees 4 bytes

Comment: Please edit your question to give a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  So a small program anyone can compile (with an int main()) which has been reduced to just what's needed to give the problem.  Include what compiler and OS you are using, and the precise command line you are using to invoke the compiler, and the exact text of the warning message you are receiving.

Comment: It is not at all clear how you have arrived to the conclusion in the title.

Comment: The warning is in the title...

Comment: The example is **literally** what is written there. I get that warning in that line, regardless of where I put it. There's no main, I'm compiling a framework.

Comment: @JoséTeixeira If *I* tried to compile all the code you gave, I would get something like "unknown identifier `main_controller`" and "unknown identifier `realm`". You're supposed to provide enough code to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The actual warning is called `-Wover-aligned` and means exactly what it says in the tin. The structure is given some alignment, i.e `__attribute__((aligned(256))` and the default allocator, i.e `operator new` is not suitably overloaded to handle this case.

Comment: @Angew, like I said, this is a top level class, spanning several layers into the object graph. It's _huge_ and not practical at all to post here (we're talking several hundreds of classes here). However, this is a issue related with memory alignment, I don't see the requirement for this _specific_ code.  I get it that the question appears too broad, but it really isn't; it's a question about unaligned allocation.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper that's what I'm looking for. I'm not using `__attribute__`, would you know what could cause this? If not `operator new`, should I use `malloc` instead?

Comment: @JoséTeixeira that's why you shouldn't post *that* class here, but a [mcve] instead. You can find the *requirement* here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JoséTeixeira If it's too big, you will never be able to track down the error in it, and neither will we. Start throwing stuff out until the error disappears. Then re-add the last bit thrown out, and start throwing *different* stuff out. Rinse and repeat. When you can no longer throw anything else out, you've built an MCVE, and you can post that in your question. Or the solution will be obvious to you from that MCVE, in which case hooray!, problem solved. If general enough, you can then post a self-answered question; if not, you will still have your solution.

Comment: I guess you guys are missing the point. He did say that couldn't reduce the problem. And the question is about causes and solutions for the warning, not the specific code. The SO guidelines work for the general case, but you guys are deviating the discussion instead of trying to help. The point being, unless you know how to alloc memory that is not 4 bytes aligned, leave it alone.